# Get the first value from a javascript array within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

### CLICK FOR DEMO

In the example below I am unable to get `pick[0]` to retrive the correct value.

If `pick[0]` is hardcoded with one of the object values e.g `A[0]` the code works as expected.

**QUESTION**

How can I retrieve the first array value from the javascript object depending on the array selected?

**JQUERY**

```
var pick = $( "#select option:selected" ).text(),
    myArray = {
      A: ['#004d94', '#0073b9'],
      B: ['#f6f0c1', '#b9cdaf']
    };

$(function () {
    $('.Bx').css('background', myArray.pick[0]);
    $('.Tx').text(pick);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick the value inside the change handler:

```
myArray[this.value][0]
```

***Snippet***:

```js
var myArray = {
      A: ['#004d94', '#0073b9'],
      B: ['#f6f0c1', '#b9cdaf']
    };


$('#select').change(function () {
    $('.Bx').css('background', myArray[this.value][0]);
    $('.Tx').text(this.value + " = " + myArray[this.value][0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<div class="Bx">COLOUR CHANGE</div>
SELECTED: <div class="Tx"></div>
```

---

As per the comments, if you need to pre-populate on page load.. just make sure the first options is `selected` and then pick that up.

***Something like this***:

```js
var myArray = {
      A: ['#004d94', '#0073b9'],
      B: ['#f6f0c1', '#b9cdaf']
    };


goChange($("#select")[0].value);

$('#select').change(function () {
    goChange(this.value);
});

function goChange(val) {
    $('.Bx').css('background', myArray[val][0]);
    $('.Tx').text(val);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="A" selected>A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<div class="Bx">COLOUR CHANGE</div>
SELECTED: <div class="Tx"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer however I also need to populate on page load. Is it not possible to use a variable in this case?

Comment: Not really. Just pick the selected one from the dropdown. Just a second updating the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To link the text of the selected option to the corresponding property;

```
$('.Bx').css('background', myArray[$("#select option:selected").text()][0]);
```

Comment: Thanks alex I tried this previously and know it works however I am attempting to change to a variable to to prevent having to repeat code. The $("#select option:selected").text() will be used many times in my actual script. Can I use a variable and if not do you know why?

Comment: `$("option:selected", this)` is an alternative or abhitalks solution.